# Ocaml how get https url

Tags: ssl, https, ocaml

How can I get the page to https? Tried that.

```
open Sys 
open Array
open Str
open List
open Printf
open Unix
open Http_client.Convenience
open Nethttp
open Http_client.Convenience
open Netsys_tls;;
let provider = Netsys_tls.current_tls();;
let tls_config = 
  Netsys_tls.create_x509_config
     ~system_trust:true
     ~peer_auth:`Required
     provider;;

let getPage _ = 
    let pipeline = new Http_client.pipeline in
    let call = new Http_client.get ("https://vk.com/") in
    call#set_redirect_mode Http_client.Do_not_redirect;
    pipeline#add call;
    pipeline#run ();
    let cookies = Header.get_set_cookie call#response_header in
    List.iter (fun c -> print_string(c.cookie_name^"="^c.cookie_value^"\n")) cookies;;

getPage();;
```

But when compiling I've got this error:

```
Error: Unbound module Netsys_tls

c:\wodi32\opt\wodi32\bin\ocamlfind ocamlopt unix.cmxa bigarray.cmxa str.cmxa -I +labltk labltk.cmxa -I c:\wodi32\opt\wodi32\lib\ocaml\pkg-lib\netsys\ netsys_oothr.cmxa netsys.cmxa -I c:\wodi32\opt\wodi32\lib\ocaml\pkg-lib\netstring\ netstring.cmxa -I c:\wodi32\opt\wodi32\lib\ocaml\pkg-lib\equeue\ equeue.cmxa -I c:\wodi32\opt\wodi32\lib\ocaml\pkg-lib\netclient\ netclient.cmxa vk.ml -I c:\wodi32\opt\wodi32\lib\ocaml\pkg-lib\equeue-ssl\ equeue_ssl.cmxa -I c:\wodi32\opt\wodi32\lib\ocaml\pkg-lib\cryptgps\ cryptgps.cmxa -o vk.exe
```

where can I get the module Netsys_tls

Comment: your problem mostly is not with OCaml, but with compilation. You need to link with the `Netsys_tls` module. It would be hard for us to give you an advice, unless we know how are you building your test program. As far as I understand, you're just trying to evaluate code in OCaml toplevel. In that case you need to issue a `#require "libname";;` command, where libname is the name of the library, that contains this module. For curl (for the example, that I've provided below, the correct invocation would be `#require "ocurl";;`. For ocamlnet, you can try to find the name using `ocamlfind list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the url, and have no other reasons to stick with OCamlnet, then you can just use `curl` library, that will take care of all caveats:

```
 let fetch fname url =
  let fd = open_in fname in
  let write s = Out_channel.output_string fd s; String.length s in
  let conn = Curl.init () in
  Curl.set_writefunction conn (write);
  Curl.set_failonerror conn true;
  Curl.set_followlocation conn true;
  Curl.set_url conn url;
  Curl.perform conn;
  Curl.cleanup conn;
  close_out fd
```

It will fetch any url supported by curl, including `https`